# How to simulate replicates for DGE analysis?

Tags: rna-seq, deseq2, transcriptome

I am prototyping with data visualization of DGE results, and I would like to work on the analysis pipeline before the real data is available. Currently, I only have 3 samples for  wild type and 1 sample for a mutant. I would like to simulate 2 extras maples of the mutant with the same variance as the wild type sample. How can I simulate data to make up for the absence of replicates in the comparison group?

My idea was to use pandas and SciPy to import the count tables, use these tools to simulate the replicates and then run DESeq2 on it. Still, I am not sure which functions I should look for once I am not so proficient with SciPy and pandas yet.